# Allocated heap discrepancy in Android Device Monitor

Tags: android

I am a beginner to Android development and currently trying to understand the problem of efficient heap usage for our application. The app plays with a lot of bitmaps, especially large offline maps used as ground overlays for Google Maps.

I use the Heap Viewer of the Android Device Manager. However, there is a big discrepancy between the "Allocated" heap (52.4MB) and the sum of "Total size" of all the items in the "stats" (around 34MB excluding the "free" item). Any possible explanation would be greatly helpful!

[image: Screenshot from Device Manager]

Comment: Since the object count also differs, my guess is that your missing space comes from the missing objects. I think you can get this same information from Android Studio itself; you might try that, as it is likely to be newer than is the Android Device Monitor.